# Почему не работает двунаправленная привязка (binding) в WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

Привязываю коллекцию людей к ListBox. Потом при нажатии на кнопку вызываются два метода. Первый меняет текущего человека, а второй меняет старую коллекцию людей на новую.
Но в интерфейсе это не отображается. По прежнему остаются старые имена людей. Хотя в разметке при binding указал Mode=TwoWay. С чем это связано?

XAML

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="218.436" Width="308.16">

<Canvas Margin="0,0,2,1">
    <ListBox x:Name="listBox" ItemsSource="{Binding People, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                              SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPerson, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                              Height="153" 
                              Width="130" 
                              Canvas.Left="10" Canvas.Top="10"/>

    <Canvas DataContext="{Binding SelectedPerson, Mode=TwoWay}" Height="60" Canvas.Left="156" Canvas.Top="10" Width="130">
        <TextBox x:Name="textBox" Text="{Binding Name}" Height="23" TextWrapping="Wrap" Canvas.Top="27" Width="77"/>
        <Label x:Name="label" Content="Имя" Height="24" Width="53"/>
    </Canvas>
    <Button x:Name="button" Content="Изменить имена" Canvas.Left="186" Canvas.Top="156" Width="100" Click="Button_Click"/>
</Canvas>
```

MainWindow

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    ApplicationViewModel vm = new ApplicationViewModel();
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        DataContext = vm;
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        vm.ChangeCurrentPerson();

        vm.ChangeListOfPersons();
    }
}
```

ViewModel

```
public class ApplicationViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<Person> People { get; set; }

    private Person selectedPerson;
    public Person SelectedPerson
    {
        get { return selectedPerson; }
        set
        {
            selectedPerson = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SelectedPhone");
        }
    }

    public ApplicationViewModel()
    {
        People = new ObservableCollection<Person>
        {
            new Person { Name = "Ivan" },
            new Person { Name = "Petr" },
        };
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string prop = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
    }

    public void ChangeCurrentPerson()
    {
        SelectedPerson = new Person() { Name = "Anton" };
    }

    public void ChangeListOfPersons()
    {
        People = new ObservableCollection<Person>
        {
            new Person { Name = "Stas" },
            new Person { Name = "Mihail" },
        };
    }
}
```

Person

```
public class Person
{
    private string name;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set
        {
            name = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Title");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string prop = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Name;
    }
}
```

Comment: `= new ObservableCollection<Person>();`

Comment: Вы комментарий выше я погляжу так и не поняли?

Comment: Не работает из-за того, что присваивается ссылка на новую коллекцию? Если я изменю имена в старой, то заработает? сейчас попробую. Если вы не это имели ввиду, то поясните пожалуйста подробнее

Comment: Вы привязали к объекту А, интерфейс это понял, отобразил данные. Потом вы создали новый объект Б, но вы не оповестили интерфейс о том, что привязываться ему теперь надо из объекта Б. Для оповещения об изменение свойства, что используется в WPF? Правильно INPC, где он у вас для `People`? Вообще по хорошему лучше не создавать коллекцию по новой, а изменять уже существующую.

Comment: Понял, спасибо.